# Display a custom script block through php on pagination page

Tags: php, pagination, logic

I have to Display a block in center in pagination page
Like the page has list of 10 Items

How can we split it in 2 parts on the page, so that After every 5th Item - i can show a custom block which is Javascript enable so as to have our custom script there

**Pager Logic**

```
   //logic of count

$model              = &$this->getModel();
$modelCategoryList  = &$this->getModel( 'list' );
$newslistTotal = $modelCategoryList->get_news_list_total();
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page'])!="")? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
$records_per_page=10;               
$offset = ($page-1) * $records_per_page;

   //display count on the pager page based on logic

      $newslist = $modelCategoryList->get_news_list($offset,$records_per_page);         
    $this->assignRef('newslist'  , $newslist);
```

**View Form**

```
if(count($this->newslist) >0){

foreach($this->newslist as $newslist)
{
    $list .='<h2><strong>'.$newslist->make.' - '.$newslist->model.'</strong></h2>
    <p>'.$newslist->n_month.' - '.$newslist->year.'</p>
    <p>'.$newslist->list_description.'</p>
    <p></p><hr/>';
        }
 }else{
$list='<div>No Listings.</div>';
  }
   ?>

      <?php echo $list?>
```

Through above logic - the items are listed on the page and further using pager logic are given page numbers.

**How to achieve on like**
so that all pages with 10 listings
can echo in like

```
      <?php echo $list1?> (of first 5 entries)

    <custom script> ........  </custom script>

      <?php echo $list2?> (of balance 5 entries)
```

**Edit**

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo for that.

```
if ($i % 5 === 0) {
   // custom code
}
```

It'll show custom code every time when modulo result will be 0 (every 5 rows).

Comment: Hello Elon, Thanks, however i think there was a problem in my code as $i integer was not working up. Have edited the question. Is there a way to do it with $count or through $newslist, so that when the count reaches 5 / 15 / 25 / 35 / 45 and goes on etc, the script tag can be shown after the entry and before 6th / 16 / 26 / 36 / 46 / 56th entry like

Comment: @RuchikaModi No, to do it you have to use `$i` var like before or change `foreach` to `for`.